# Wordpress and Rails app issue using https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx, https

I have wordpress installed in one server and Rails app in another server

Rails app contains https url in it.

when i try to call https://domain/blog page is getting loaded but css and js are not loaded.

Can anyone help in this.

Comment: Can you check logs and find out if js and css are trying to be loaded from WP or RoR? What happen when you directly request for JS or CSS file? How is your Nginx configuration?

Comment: Its loaded from WP only but it is an http request  and it throughs error in firefox console as "Blocked loading mixed active content "http://ipaddress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/genericons/genericons.css?ver=3.2

Comment: Thanks. Solved the issue. It was issue of nginx as i was using proxy pass